# glmer mixed models inconsistent between lme4 updates

Tags: r

This is a long post. I’m having trouble attaining consistent model results between lme4 versions. My old computer was running R 3.0.0 “Masked Marvel”, with the 0.999999-2 version of lme4, and my new work computer is running R 3.0.2 “Frisbee Sailing” with lme4 version 1.1-2. They are not giving me the same model outputs. Omitting the new lme4, I installed every package update on my old laptop one-by-one and ran the models. Then, updated R itself and ran the models. Finally, I made further updates to packages for R 3.0.2, and ran the models once more. They remained consistent with the original analysis. I wasn’t able to run the models with the most recent MASS package with R 3.0.0, and with the most recent nlme package in R 3.0.2. The error message I received in those cases was the same, and is below:
“Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “mer” object: Slot L must be a monotonic LL' factorization of size dims['q']”

I’m wondering if someone can help shed light on this before I update to lme4 1.1-2 to complete my analyses. There doesn’t appear to be a changelog at the address linked in R Studio…http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/lme4/NEWS

Maybe something else has changed on my end? I’ve been using the same datafile, and setting it up the same within R.

I am not sure how to attach data, or how to make this easiest for you all to run through yourselves. I can do that with some instruction. Below are the outputs for 2 models before the updates, and the same models after. The variation occurs in models that I haven't included here as well, some worse than others. It definitely affects an AIC ranking.

lme4 version 0.999999-2
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) -- "Masked Marvel"

```
at1500o <- glmer(apred ~ 
                 (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp),
                 family = binomial,
                 data = PU3.atristis)                
summary(at1500o)

Number of levels of a grouping factor for the random effects
is *equal* to n, the number of observations
Warning message: In mer_finalize(ans) : false convergence (8)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
Formula: apred ~ (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp) 
   Data: PU3.atristis 
   AIC      BIC     logLik      deviance
   182.2    193     -87.11      174.2
Random effects:
 Groups      Name           Variance    Std.Dev.  
 Eps        (Intercept)     1.6630e+01  4.0780e+00
 fFarm      (Intercept)     2.4393e+00  1.5618e+00
 fExp       (Intercept)     5.8587e-13  7.6542e-07
Number of obs: 110, groups: Eps, 110; fFarm, 17; fExp, 2

Fixed effects:
                Estimate  Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -6.1406     0.7126    -8.618   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

False convergence [didn’t seem to be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299451/warning-message-in-mixed-model-lme4)

```
at1500a <- glmer(apred ~ 
                      pctfield1500 * factor(SiteTrt) +
                      (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp),
                    family = binomial,
                    data = PU3.atristis)                
summary(at1500a)

Number of levels of a grouping factor for the random effects
is *equal* to n, the number of observations
Warning message: In mer_finalize(ans) : false convergence (8)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
Formula: apred ~ pctfield1500 + factor(SiteTrt) + pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt) + (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp) 
   Data: PU3.atristis 

   AIC      BIC     logLik      deviance
   185.2    209.5   -83.59      167.2

Random effects:
 Groups     Name            Variance    Std.Dev.  
 Eps        (Intercept)     2.4539e+01  4.95370375
 fFarm      (Intercept)     8.1397e-01  0.90220336
  fExp      (Intercept)     1.3452e-08  0.00011598
Number of obs: 110, groups: Eps, 110; fFarm, 17; fExp, 2

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate  Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                    -6.82245    2.64044    -2.584   0.00977 **
pctfield1500                   -0.01041    0.10849    -0.096   0.92353   
factor(SiteTrt)2               2.47654     3.97069     0.624   0.53282   
factor(SiteTrt)3               4.33391     4.65551     0.931   0.35190   
pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt)2  -0.05073    0.13117    -0.387   0.69895   
pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt)3  -0.05729    0.14524    -0.394   0.69323   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr)  pc1500    f(ST)2   f(ST)3  p1500:(ST)2
pctfild1500         -0.876                                 
fctr(StTr)2     -0.665  0.582                          
fctr(StTr)3     -0.571  0.504     0.380                   
p1500:(ST)2     0.724   -0.827   -0.850   -0.417            
p1500:(ST)3     0.654   -0.747   -0.435   -0.887    0.618
```

Lme4 version 1.1-2
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"

```
at1500o <- glmer(apred ~ 
                 (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp),
                 family = binomial,
                 data = PU3.atristis)                
summary(at1500o)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: apred ~ (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp) 
   Data: PU3.atristis 

      AIC           BIC         logLik      deviance 
      236.8296      247.6316    -114.4148   228.8296 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name           Variance    Std.Dev. 
 Eps        (Intercept)     4.799e+01   6.927e+00
 fFarm      (Intercept)     6.542e-01   8.088e-01
 fExp       (Intercept)     6.056e-10   2.461e-05
Number of obs: 110, groups: Eps, 110; fFarm, 17; fExp, 2

Fixed effects:
             Estimate     Std. Error     z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -7.975        1.115        -7.154   8.43e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

No warnings anymore, but everything is pretty different. The model fit statement has changed from the Laplace approximation, to maximum likelihood [‘glmerMod’].

```
at1500a <- glmer(apred ~ 
                      pctfield1500 * factor(SiteTrt) +
                      (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp),
                    family = binomial,
                    data = PU3.atristis)                
summary(at1500a)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: apred ~ pctfield1500 + factor(SiteTrt) + pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt) + (1 | fFarm) + (1 | Eps) + (1 | fExp) 
   Data: PU3.atristis 

      AIC           BIC         logLik      deviance 
      242.7874      267.0917    -112.3937   224.7874 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name            Variance    Std.Dev. 
 Eps        (Intercept)     3.346e+01   5.784e+00
 fFarm      (Intercept)     1.809e-07   4.253e-04
 fExp       (Intercept)     4.380e-11   6.618e-06
Number of obs: 110, groups: Eps, 110; fFarm, 17; fExp, 2

Fixed effects:
                              Estimate  Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                   -7.46800      3.04197     -2.455    0.0141 *
pctfield1500                   0.00032      0.12301     0.003     0.9979  
factor(SiteTrt)2               2.05618      4.57444     0.450     0.6531  
factor(SiteTrt)3               6.72139      5.20895     1.290     0.1969  
pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt)2 -0.04882      0.14911     -0.327    0.7434  
pctfield1500:factor(SiteTrt)3 -0.11324      0.16495     -0.686    0.4924  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)  pc1500    f(ST)2   f(ST)3  p1500:(ST)2
pctfild1500 -0.875                                 
fctr(StTr)2 -0.665  0.582                          
fctr(StTr)3 -0.584  0.511     0.388                   
p1500:(ST)2 0.722   -0.825   -0.850   -0.422            
p1500:(ST)3 0.653   -0.746   -0.434   -0.886    0.615
```

Cheers,
Nava

Comment: a couple of quick points: (1) `NEWS` is available at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html or (development version) https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/inst/NEWS.Rd ; release notes for the big update at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/misc/notes/release_notes.md . (2) You can install the `lme4.0` package from `http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos` for backward compatibility ... (3) posting your data to some publicly accessible web site is probably easiest.

Comment: PS not necessarily relevant, but you probably shouldn't be trying to fit a factor with only two levels as a random effect -- it won't work well.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. glmer won't work well, or the model won't work well? Both? The problem I was running into was that I wanted to include the variation from the 2 experiments, but didn't want to push the number of fixed variables in the model beyond what my sample size could handle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both, but mostly the latter.  Estimating a variance from two observations, which is essentially what you're doing here, generally gives a very poor estimate. The MLE will often come out to zero (even when the true value is non-zero), and will be biased too. You only save one parameter by treating experiment as a random effect instead of a fixed effect.  See http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#fixed_vs_random for more information.

Comment: OK, I've got an idea. That was an interesting synthesis on fixed/random philosophy. Thanks again for the detailed response, as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.0 of the `lme4` package marked a major change, with a pretty substantial rework of the underlying fitting code. From the [changelog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html):

> Because the internal computational machinery has changed, results from
>   the newest version of lme4 will not be numerically identical to those
>   from previous versions. For reasonably well- defined fits, they will
>   be extremely close (within numerical tolerances of 1e-4 or so), but
>   for unstable or poorly-defined fits the results may change, and very
>   unstable fits may fail when they (apparently) succeeded with previous
>   versions. Similarly, some fits may be slower with the new version,
>   although on average the new version should be faster and more stable.
>   More numerical tuning options are now available (see below);
>   non-default settings may restore the speed and/or ability to fit a
>   particular model without an error. If you notice significant or
>   disturbing changes when fitting a model with the new version of lme4,
>   please notify the maintainers.

Considering your model fits using the 0.9999 version of `lme4` produced false convergence warnings, your model might be in the "unstable fits" category this is talking about.

Comment: They may be! Thanks for finding that for me.